# Unable to get the Angular Material Auto Complete Values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i am trying to Create a autocomplete filter and from a array and when i am trying to use it is displaying to lower case is now a function
below is my code

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.Address}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

.ts code:

```
 myControl = new FormControl();
  options:any [] = [
    
        {
            "Id": "SO5",
            "Address": "Wall Street. New York City"
           
        },
        {
            "Id": "65",
            "Address": "Wall Street. New York City"
        },
        {
            "buyerId": "63g",
            "Address": "Dallas"
        }

  ]
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value:any):any[] {
    console.log(value);
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

below is my stackblitz link    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygzpcz

Answer (score 0):

`options` is an array of objects. There is no `toLowerCase` method on object.

You should be using `option.Address` instead:

```
return this.options.filter(option => option.Address.toLowerCase()
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, in case of objects you should create displayWith method in order to map object to desired diplayed value:

**html**

```
<mat-autocomplete ... [displayWith]="displayWith">
```

**ts**

```
displayWith(item: any) {
  return item ? item.Address : ''
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygzpcz-y6axjd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)**